# Erros mysql sendo apresentados em francês

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Todos os erros que eu recebo referente ao banco de dados phpmyadmin são em Frances. Porém, o painel está em pt-br, apenas os erros de consulta -um select por exemplo- são exibidos em francês.
Utilizo o WAMP.

EX: `Aucune base n'a �t� s�lectionn�e`

Comment: qual servidor usa?wamp?

Comment: Sim! Desculpe-me, esqueci de informar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para trocar a linguagem que o MySQL usa você deve mudar uma configuração no arquivo: "my.ini"

Procure por essa linha:

```
# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=
```

O seu provavelmente deve estar configurado desta maneira

```
# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

Troque para "en-us". Não me recordo se "pt-br" está disponível.
Após salvar o arquivo você deve reiniciar os serviços do MySQL pelo Wamp.

Comment: Obrigado, resposta perfeita!

Answer (score 2):

Clique no ícone do Wamp, e em seguida clique em MySQL e em my.ini

[image: wamp]

Abra esse arquivo com o bloco de notas, dê um CTRL+F e procure por:

```
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

Comente essa linha com **#**  e substitua por:

```
 lc-messages=pt_BR
```

Reinicie o WAMP e pronto.

Comment: Resolvido! As duas respostas estão corretas, mas ele respondeu antes, entao irei marcar a dele. De qualquer forma, obrigado!